# Substrate API not working with parity polkadot node after upgrade

Tags: sidecar

I am running polkadot node with docker  - parity/polkadot:v0.9.30
and sidecar with parity/substrate-api-sidecar:v14.0.1 , the node synched to the latest, but when tried to query the sidecar, getting bad gateway error.

Earlier to this I have parity/substrate-api-sidecar:v12.4.3 and parity/polkadot:v0.9.27 ;  using these I am able to get the data, after moving to latest version getting error
Please suggest me here

Comment: AFAIK sidecar v14.0.1 is compatible with Polkadot v0.9.29. For Polkadot v0.9.30 you should try sidecar v14.1.0.

Comment: I have tried the sidecar v14.1.0 , but still , i am getting the '502 bad gateway' error